# Comunicação do APP com Servidor Web

Tags: java, android, web-service, http, http-request

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma, em questão de segurança/performance, de fazer minha aplicação mobile/android se comunicar com um servidor web (apache/php, por exemplo) para receber/enviar dados.

A idéia é fazer com que, de tempos em tempos, minha aplicação mobile consulte o servidor web pra obter dados, pensei a principio em fazer via Http Request (GET) obtendo o resultado no formato JSON, porém minha dúvida é se essa é a melhor forma de se fazer. Sei que poderia ser via Web Service também.

Só existem estas duas opções de "conversa" (http / webservice)?

Ou existe algum outro modelo, tal como via sockets numa determinada porta pra ser mais rápido?

Aguardo a dica de vocês.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a biblioteca oficial do Google para isto, o `Volley`. É muito fácil de implementar e existem vários exemplos (além da documentação oficial).

Juntamente com o `Volley`, recomendo você utilizar o `OkHttp`, que melhora e otimiza suas requisições juntamente com o `Volley`.

- Volley

[Documentação oficial do `Volley`](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

[Um tutorial em português bem bacana que pode te ajudar](http://www.thiengo.com.br/volley-no-android-entendendo-e-utilizando)

- OkHttp

[Site oficial do `OkHttp`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

[Uma referência de como utilizar o `Volley` + `Okhttp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375043/how-to-implement-android-volley-with-okhttp-2-0)