# Quais melhores práticas ao implementar requisições?

Tags: java, android

Ao implementar chamadas a um *webservice* tenho trabalhado com o seguinte esquema: implemento uma classe que estende `AsynkTask` e dentro do método `doInBackground()` realizo a chamada ao meu serviço. Uma particularidade aqui, é que em vez de usar a classe `HttpUrlConnection` tenho utilizado um *framework* do Spring, [Spring for Android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/), que fornece uma série de facilidades, dentre elas a coesão do código.

Embora funcione perfeitamente este esquema é um tanto improdutivo e, até mesmo, cansativo. Pois, para cada requisição preciso implementar uma nova `AsyncTask`.

Existe alguma boa prática, mesmo que não oficial, ou alguma abordagem que a comunidade tem adotado de modo a facilitar o desenvolvimento de chamadas a um *webservice* e diminuir a quantidade de código implementado para este fim?

Comment: Veja se esta resposta te ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53758/comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-app-com-servidor-web/53761#53761

Answer (score 10):

Se você estiver usando JSON, você pode usar o [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) para fazer as requisições. No Retrofit é possível fazer chamadas síncronas e assíncronas, no caso de chamadas assíncronas (fora da *UIThread*), você precisaria fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
// Annotation para especificar uma requisição ao webservice
@GET("/usuarios/{id}/compra")

// Nome do método que fará a requisição
void getCompraUsuario(@Path("id") int id, Callback<Compra> callback);
```

Nesse caso, o método `getCompraUsuario` fará a requisição ao webservice e enviará a resposta para o `callback`, que retorna a compra do usuario.

Answer (score 3):

Existem diversas formas de fazer requisições a WebServices, através de código que no caso se tornaria muito extenso ou através de APIs, uma forma bem simplificada de se fazer tais requisições são dessas maneiras:

http://pt.slideshare.net/AlexandreAntunes3/consumindo-dados-via-web-service-no-android

http://zbra.com.br/2011/03/30/consumindo-web-service-em-aplicacoes-android/

Lembrando que há métodos usando REST com PHP também.

Note que há um framework muito bom chamado "Spring", ele é bem dinâmico e confiável!
Confira no segundo link o uso dele.
Caso queira entender como funciona e como implementar de forma simplificada um WebService, consulte o segundo link.
Espero ter ajudado! Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Atualmente o Android tem adotado a biblioteca para requisições HTTP do `java.net`. As bibliotecas recomendadas antes dessa eram do pacote apache. O Google juntamente com a AOSP, estão desenvolvendo uma biblioteca chamada [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) muito leve e poderosa. Eu recomendo você utilizar a Volley que em um futuro próximo será a biblioteca padrão para requisição web, mas é importante saber a diferença entre elas. Nesse [link](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/volley-vs-retrofit---a-battle-royale) tem uma comparação bem interessante sobre Volley e Retrofit (mencionada pelo regmoraes acima). Mas nada melhor que comparar as bibliotecas em casos específicos.

Veja também como adicionar a Vooley como dependência no Gradle [(android-volley)](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley).